# SQL statement to collect data over granular time span

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have collected CPU usage data on my server using the following SQL Server 2008 table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [tbl] 
[id] BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[dt] DATETIME2,   -- date/time when CPU usage was collected
[usage] TINYINT   -- value from [0 to 100]
```

This data is logged by a service running on the server with a frequency of approx. 5 minutes.

So my goal now is to draw a graph that shows CPU usage over time. For that an end-user is allowed to specify the "from" and "to" dates for the graph, and the graph itself is broken into N data points. (For simplicity, let's say that N is 24.)

I came up with the following SQL statement to retrieve N (or 24) data points of the CPU usage to plot on my graph:

```
SELECT COUNT([usage]), SUM([usage]) FROM [tbl] 
 WHERE [dt]>='_DateDataPoint0_' AND [dt]<'_DateDataPoint1_'
UINON ALL
SELECT COUNT([usage]), SUM([usage]) FROM [tbl] 
 WHERE [dt]>='_DateDataPoint1_' AND [dt]<'_DateDataPoint2_'
--and so on, until Nth data point
```

In case:

```
"from" = June 14, 2013, 00:00:00
"to" = June 15, 2013, 00:00:00
```

I get the following data point date/times:

```
_DateDataPoint0_ = 2013-06-14 00:00:00
_DateDataPoint1_ = 2013-06-14 01:00:00
_DateDataPoint2_ = 2013-06-14 02:00:00
and so on ...
_DateDataPoint23_ = 2013-06-14 23:00:00
_DateDataPoint24_ = 2013-06-15 00:00:00
```

So at the end my ASP.NET script receives N pairs of data:

```
Count_Usage_DataPointN
Sum_Usage_DataPointN
```

So to get a usage number at a particular data point I do this:

```
Usage_N = Sum_Usage_DataPointN / Count_Usage_DataPointN
```

First, I'm curious if this is the correct way of doing it?

And, secondly, I'm curious about some strange result of the selection above. Say, if I have a time span of 1 hour, the resulting CPU usage data has higher spikes than, say, for a time span of 1 day, or a month. Is this normal? It seems like the longer the time span the flatter my graph becomes.

Answer (score 1):

This would be expected because you have a fixed number of datapoints on your graph.

You have divided your graph into 24 points. Say you wanted to display 2 days worth of data. When you distribute hourly over 24 points, the average value (sum/count) would flatten . To display each individual spike you would need 48 points on your axis.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So I shouldn't be worried about, right?

Comment: Whether I select one or many days, I would like to see the same data and the same height of spikes, regardless of the timespan. So this would not be my preferred solution. Having hourly data, I would stick with rendering 1 point per hour.

Comment: So what you said above is that you prefer to see a horizontal line. I'm sorry, I'm not following you...